# Sublime Text build system not working when put in variants

Tags: c, build, sublimetext3, sublimetext, build-system

I have this user build system `C Terminal.sublime-build` to compile and run c programs:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["gcc.exe", "-std=c11", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/c", "$file_base_name & echo. & echo. & pause"],
    "shell": true,
    "selector": "source.c"
}
```

I use it to compile and run some of my C single files and it works perfectly.

However, when I put it into the default `C Single File.sublime-build` as a variant like this:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "gcc \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell_cmd": "gcc \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
        },

        {
            "name": "Terminal",
            "cmd": ["gcc.exe", "-std=c11", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/c", "$file_base_name & echo. & echo. & pause"],
            "shell": true
        }
    ]
}
```

When I select the `C Single File - Terminal` build system and build, the terminal doesn't pop up and it says `[Finished in 0.3s]` in the Sublime output.

Does anyone know do I get the build system variant to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work for you because the main build (and the other variant) use `shell_cmd` to specify what is to be executed, but that variant uses `cmd` instead. You shouldn't mix those in a build.

Variants apply their keys on top of the base build when they're selected, which allows them to override the top level build keys and change the build. The main build uses `shell_cmd`, but the `Terminal` variant uses `cmd`.

When the variant keys are applied, that makes the build have both a `shell_cmd` and a `cmd` in the build, and internally the `exec` command favours `shell_cmd` over `cmd`, which means that for your variant it's actually still executing the top level build.

This is visible in the console. After you execute your build, if you check in the Sublime console (`View > Show Console`) you can see a log that shows you what command it executed. It's actually executing the top level build, which is compiling and nothing else.

To solve the problem you need to either adjust the variant to also use `shell_cmd` instead, or inside of the variant add `"shell_cmd": null` to override it, which will cause it to use `cmd` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! I added `"shell_cmd": null` to the variants and it works perfectly now!